# generating css captcha images (letter and white noise)

Tags: css, image, captcha

I am looking for sources to make css captcha images (letters with white noise).

I am going to make something like this:

[image: a][image: c][image: e][image: s][image: x![z]

Do you have any sources / tutorials which I can use ?

Thank you for your answers or ideas

My ideas:

1. Make gifs of letters
2. make css box with white noise filter
   ...

Comment: Are you asking how to make the images themselves or the processing of captcha creation and validating the generated captcha against user input?

Comment: Is `Photoshop` available to you?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?csw=1. Why reinvent the wheel? Just use the PHP implementation at the link above.

Comment: @hungerstar yes, I have photoshop (at work) , but I prefer GIMP, but I  want this to be generated by css, not making gif images ( last scenario if I can't do this by css )

Comment: @adaam I am not reinventing wheel, just adjusting captcha to page design

Comment: Wait, did you say generated by CSS?

Comment: @MrLister  I put letter in div, then apply noise filter and result is in page (as images showing)

Comment: Are you trying to create a captcha?  Or just styleing something else to look like a captcha?  Because you wouldn't want the actual letter anywhere in the code.  That would defeat the purpose of the captcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nice tutorial how to make moving noise background

here is a tutorial

http://blog.jerrettwhite.com/2012/09/moving-noise-background.html